# How to call multiple get methods in Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, routes

Hi I am developing web api application with angularjs. I have GET three methods in one controller and none of them are calling. For example,

```
 public class usersController : ApiController
    {
        //First Get method.
        [HttpGet]
        [SuperAdmin]
        [LoginCheck]
        [ActionName("me")]
        public HttpResponseMessage me()
        {
        }

        //second Get method.
        [LoginCheck]
        [SuperAdmin]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {

        }

        //third Get method.
        [HttpGet]
        [LoginCheck]
        [SuperAdmin]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)
        {
        }
```

I am calling using below code.

```
this.getSubs = function () {
        var role = "SUPER_ADMIN";
        //role is optional here
        var url = '/api/users/' + role;
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    this.getcurrentuser = function () {
        var url = '/api/users/me/';
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    this.getSubsbyID = function (id) {
        var url = '/api/users/' + id;
        return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
```

My routing is as follows.

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am not able to call any of three methods using angularjs. May i know where i am doing routing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you post the service(or controller) in which you have those methods implemented? This problem can be for many reasons, please, provide more info.

Comment: IF you think is a routing problem, then post your routing as well

Comment: Thank you. I am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) http://localhost:22045/api/users/SUPER_ADMIN

Comment: Are you using any proxy server like apache or nginx?

Comment: No i am  running in localhost.

Comment: Then change your url to  var url = 'http://localhost:22045/api/users/

Comment: I fixed some syntex errors in agular and i am able to call   var url = '/api/users/' + id; but not other functions

Answer (score 1):

Two things one is this might be a problem with your requests being a CORS request.  You may need to enable CORS.  First you would want to install the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and then you would add to your api config file before your routing calls.

```
config.EnableCors();
```

Second it might be helpful to adjust your routing to use attribute routing.  WebApi doesn't support Action routing like a normal MVC controller might.  You might have some routing already setup in your config file, something like

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This would allow you to call the controller users but I find it problematic trying to get an ApiController to call the appropriate GET method using the signature.  I would recommend you use attribute routing.  If it's not already there you can add attribute routing to your config

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then you can setup your HttpGet attribute routing like so.

```
public class usersController : ApiController
{
        //First Get method.
        [HttpGet]
        [SuperAdmin]
        [LoginCheck]
        [Route("api/users/me")] // this is your routing attribute
        public HttpResponseMessage me()
        {
        }

        //second Get method.
        [LoginCheck]
        [SuperAdmin]
        [Route("api/users/{id:int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {

        }

        //third Get method.
        [HttpGet]
        [LoginCheck]
        [SuperAdmin]
        [Route("api/users/{role}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)
        {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I am calling three apis on page load. On page load 3 times i am hitting to same below url.  [Route("api/users/{role}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)

Comment: Did you update your routing config and add config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); The [Route] won't work unless that line is there. Also this needs to be before any other routing, but after config.EnableCors(); (if you're using cors)

Comment: Cors i enabled and no problem. config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); i have.

Comment: sorry I forgot to include the int constraint notice [Route("api/users/{id:int}")]